# where is "SERVER.APP" in Snow Leopard OSX server?

Tags: osx-server

The textbook answer to stopping the server in OSX Leopard server is to remove the SERVER.APP. Unfortunately I can't find it anywhere, visible or not. Where should I be looking ? Is it's absence related to "available servers (0)"?

Comment: The [textbooks I use for server operating system and apps are all written by Arek Dreyer](https://www.peachpit.com/authors/bio/a9630bb1-0822-4f4b-b710-3c3dbdfbc232) - if you want to link to your research, we might have something better than the existing very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Server.app" does not exist in **Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server** as the *server* aspects of the **OS** are integrated into the **OS** itself, as in everything came preinstalled. Below you'll see a screen shot of the **Applications** *folder*, with the **Server** *folder* selected and there is no "Server.app".

In **Terminal** using the following *command*, it did not find  "Server.app":

```
find / -iname '*server*'
```

It found a lot of things with "server" in its name but none explicitly "Server.app".

That said, the current [**macOS Server**](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/os-x-server/id883878097) available from the **App Store** contains "Server.app", per its tech specs page [macOS Server Tech Specs](https://www.apple.com/macos/server/specs/), under **What’s Included in macOS Server** it shows:

- Server app

---

[image: Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server]